# How to set xkb variant in sway for one of multiple layouts

Tags: keyboard-layout, wayland, xkb, sway

I want to set the German layout with nodeadkeys as default, and the other layouts with default variant.
It works when I set just the German layout and its variant, but not with multiple layouts:

```bash
input * {
    xkb_layout de,eu,us
    # All the variants I tried
    xkb_variant nodeadkeys
    xkb_variant nodeadkeys,,
    xkb_variant nodeadkeys,eu,us
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
input "type:keyboard" {          
    xkb_layout us,de(nodeadkeys)
    xkb_options caps:swapescape,grp:rctrl_toggle
}
```

Comment: thank you, seems to work - I also tried `xkb_layout de,eu,us
 xkb_variant nodeadkeys,basic,euro` successfully now :)